# Fancybox callback to move owl carousel to fancybox index #

Tags: jquery, callback, fancybox, owl-carousel

I'm trying to combine the Fancybox lightbox with an owl carousel.

Within all image links I have: -

```
data-fancybox="gallery"
```

triggered via: -

```
$(function () {
    $('[data-fancybox="gallery"]').fancybox({
        buttons: [
            "close"
        ],
        loop: true
    });
```

And I know I can programatically move the owl carousel to an item (e.g. #4) using: -

```
$('#thumbGalleryDetail2').trigger('to.owl.carousel', 4)
```

Everything works OK but I'd like the owl carousel to move to the last viewed image in the fancybox. I gather I need a callback from fancybox for this, but am unsure how to do it and there isn't much documentation on callbacks from fancybox. I can't even get a simple console.log to work on closing fancybox and I've tried a **lot** of different examples.

One complication, if it can work, is that the fancybox index starts at 1 and the owl index starts at 0, so the fancybox callback would have to be to it's index -1.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Edited to add solution: -

```
$(function () {
    $('[data-fancybox="gallery"]').fancybox({
        buttons: [
            "close"
        ],
        loop: true,
        afterShow : function( instance, current ) {
            // console.log(current.index);
            $('#thumbGalleryDetail2').trigger('to.owl.carousel', current.index)
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: See this demo https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/NLQZBr?editors=1010 as a reference on how to synchronize with a slider

Comment: Excellent, thanks very much! I've added the solution to my question.